# Problem in converting React Navigation v3 to v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Can someone help me how to convert this to the v5 syntax?

```js
const Navigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    [screens.App]: AppNavigator,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: screens.Init,
    headerMode: 'screen',
  },
);
const RootNavigator = createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

```
export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    [screens.Auth]: AuthScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteKey: screens.Auth,
    headerMode: 'screen',
  },
);
```

I can't seem to solve my problem, my brain is aching as hell. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: There is no switch navigator in v5. You could reference this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283752/8268484

Comment: Please read the upgrade guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html