# unable to use createSwitchNavigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am not able to use createSwithNavigator in creation of my app.I want to create a switchNavigator between my loginflow and mainflow of my app.Pls help me in figuring out what can be used and what changes can be made.

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup:SignupScreen,
    Signin:SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    trackListFlow: createStackNavigator({
      TrackList:TrackListScreen,
      TrackDetail:TrackDetailScreen
    }),
    TrackCreate:TrackCreateScreen,
    Account:AccountScreen,
  })
})

export default createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
```

Comment: Could you write down the errors that you've got, please?

Comment: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Module.../../../../../../../../../Desktop/exercise/tracks/node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs/lib/module/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js

Comment: Which navigation version you're using currently? `v4` or `v5`?

Comment: I am using v5, It does not support switch navigator and many other things

Comment: Probably you can find a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60279165/where-is-placed-createswitchnavigator-in-react-navigation-5-x-for-migrating-from)